# RPM Build with Gradle

Tags: gradle, build, rpm, packaging

Does anyone have a good idea about building rpm packages from multiple artifacts with its dependencies like maven.

example: proj1.4.1.0 and its dependencies & proj2.4.1.0 and its dependencies.

How can i define gradle build to pull these artifacts from nexus and build rpm packages, with both of the projects with their own dependencies in different directory structure.

So my target would be

```
/some/installation/dir/projec_1/lib & /some/installation/dir/proj_2/lib,
/some/installation/dir/projec_1/bin & /some/installation/dir/proj_2/bin 
/some/installation/dir/projec_1/scripts & /some/installation/dir/proj_2/scripts
```

Comment: have you looked into the nebula ospackage plugin? https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin

Comment: Yes, I did but it is not telling me how to achieve what i want. Those release version to be picked up from nexus and put it into rpm package to be installed in target dirs.

Answer (score 1):

Check this example. The build.gradle file content will be like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "nebula.ospackage" version "3.2.0"
}


task one(type: Rpm) {
    packageName = 'one-pack'
    version = '1.0.0'
    release = '1'
    arch = I386
    os = LINUX

    from('./src/main/resources') {
        into 'apps/lib/'
    }
}

task two(type: Rpm) {
    packageName = 'two-pack'
    version = '2.2.0'
    release = '2'
    arch = I386
    os = LINUX
}

apply plugin: 'nebula.ospackage'

group 'com.avishek'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.2.0'
}
```

And you can create RPM like this:

```
./gradlew clean two one
```